# Vim Color Scheme for specific filetype

Tags: vim

Is it possible to setup a specific colorscheme for a specific filetype in a vimrc file?

PlainBoringWhite for .txt

SomethingDarkBackdround for .c or .rb

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @Rein mentioned, you can use autocommand to achieve what you want. Add something like this to your .vimrc file:

```
"default colorscheme
colorscheme solarized

"different colorscheme for ruby and markdown
autocmd FileType ruby colorscheme railcasts
autocmd FileType markdown colorscheme mac_classic
```

Comment: This will cause vim to change the colorscheme for markdown and ruby but it will not return it to solarized when a different file type is opened (such as yaml for example)

Answer (score 3):

While you could use an aucommand to set a specific colorscheme for a specific filetype or filename pattern, it is more common to use a syntax file to define highlight groups for elements and then use your global colorscheme to handle coloring of those groups.